# SQLite3 sqlite3_open succeeds, sqlite3_exec fails with CANTOPEN (error 14)

Tags: c, sqlite

I have this code, which uses SQLite in C:

```
int settings_set(const char *name, const char *value) {
    int r = SQLITE_ERROR;
    int res = sqlite3_open(PERSISTENTDB, &db_persistent);
    if (SQLITE_OK == res) {
        char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("REPLACE INTO settings VALUES ('%q', '%q')", name, value);
        r = sqlite3_exec(db_persistent, sql, 0, 0, 0);
        if (SQLITE_OK == r) {
            log_write(LVL_NOTICE, "[data] set setting '%s' to '%s'\n", name, value);
        } else {
            log_write(LVL_NOTICE, "[data] failed to set setting '%s' to '%s': code %d\n", name, value, r);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db_persistent);
        sqlite3_free(sql);
    } else {
        log_write(LVL_NOTICE, "[data] settings_set(): could not open persistent database: code %d\n", res);
    }

    return r;
}
```

When this code is run as root (the database file is set `rw-rw-rw-` and owned by root), this works fine. When run as `nobody`, I get an error code 14 (`SQLITE_CANTOPEN`) on the `sqlite3_exec` call. So, apparently the `sqlite3_open` call succeeds. I would expect this error to occur on the open call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your non-root user probably doesn't have the permission to create and write to new files in the directory hosting the database.

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#cantopen) for that error code states:

> The file in question might be a primary database file **or on of several temporary disk files**.

SQLite creates temporary files, at least when you modify the database. If your non-root process can't create those, you'll get that error. You could verify that by running your program in `strace`, e.g. something like:

```
strace -e trace=open ./a.out
```

You'll see which calls to `open` are failing (probably for the journal file), and for what reason.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Setting the dir to `rw-rw-rw` fixed it (I have no `strace` on that system, it is an embedded device).